# How to create an Amplify Datastore many-to-many schema in version 3.7.3

Tags: aws-amplify

I'm trying to set up a simple many-to-many relationship in Amplify Datastore using the new @hasMany directive. Unfortunately, there is no documentation other than "if you want to store additional properties on the join table, or if you have an existing join table, you can continue to use two @hasMany <=> @belongsTo relationships to facilitate a many-to-many relationship".

I want to have tables for warehouses and parts with a many-to-many relationship that tracks the in-stock quantity of a particular part at a particular warehouse:

```
type Part @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!  
  inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(indexName: "warehousesByPart", fields: ["id"])
}

type Warehouse @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(indexName: "partsByWarehouse", fields: ["id"])
}

type Inventory  @model {
    id: ID!
    warehouseId: ID! @index(name: "partsByWarehouse", sortKeyFields: ["partId"])
    partId: ID! @index(name: "warehousesByPart", sortKeyFields: ["warehouseId"])
    part: Part! @belongsTo(fields: ["partId"])
    warehouse: Warehouse! @belongsTo(fields: ["warehouseId"])
    inStock: Int!
}
```

This is a front-end implementation only. Amplify CLI is the latest version (7.6.5). The error I get is

> Error processing @hasMany directive on Warehouse.inventories, @index
> directive with name partsByWarehouse was not found in connected model
> Inventory

What am I doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the sequence of the types and added a primaryKey to the m2m table. The "Part" type has to be listed last in the schema, otherwise you will get an error. This is not documented anywhere as far as I can tell. I noticed that you will get errors when you flip the sequence even in the examples listed in aws docs. This is using amplify-modelgen. Also note much better documentation in the API (GraphQL) section of amplify's docs than in the Datastore section.

```
type Warehouse @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(indexName: "partsByWarehouse", fields: ["id"])
}

type Inventory  @model {
    partId: ID! @primaryKey(sortKeyFields: ["warehouseId"])
    warehouseId: ID! @index(name: "partsByWarehouse")
    part: Part! @belongsTo(fields: ["partId"])
    warehouse: Warehouse! @belongsTo(fields: ["warehouseId"])
    inStock: Int!
}

type Part @model {
  id: ID!
  description: String!  
  inventories: [Inventory] @hasMany(fields: ["id"]) 
}
```